# Filter values of dropdown list with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created a dynamic drop down menu in my Sheets file to manage the selection of loading docks. I would like to have as data in the drop down menu the docks that are not already assigned in the "Planning" tab as well as the docks that are not out of order in the DB tab.

Could you please help me with this? I can't seem to add the "filter" on the out of service platforms.

Here is what the "Planning" tab looks like:

[image]

Here is the "BDD" tab:

[image]

And here is the formula used to generate the list that populates the drop down menu in the "Platform" column on the "Schedule" tab:

```
=query(query({F2:F;Planning!K2:K};"Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1<>'' group by Col1");"Select Col1 where Col2=1")
```

Also, if you know another way to avoid having "invalid" present in the cells where the dock is selected (via an onEdit() function for example, I'm interested).

Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT :
Sorry for my late reply. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RP5C8E9fluLxoGMUel6sWsZDu11oAH4_Chm5bHpgMh8/edit#gid=1070598266) is a copy of the file.
In the "BDD" tab, column C is used to populate the drop-down menu of the Planning tab. It is made up of the docks in column 1. However, I would like one of them to be "Out of service", so it is no longer present in the drop-down menu (wish in column D).

Comment: Could you please [share a copy / sample of your sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?#share_publicly) with an example of the desired output?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I edited py post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Google Sheets:

Use this to create the dropdown list:

```js
=FILTER(A2:A;ISNA(MATCH(VALUE(A2:A);Planning!C2:C;0));B2:B<>"Hors Service")
```

This is filterting **out** all values that are already selected and which `STATE OF BLOCK` is set to "Hors Service"

---

### Apps Script:

This script will remove the data validation from the cell after selecting a one value, then it will add it back if all values in the cell are deleted (It takes a few seconds for it to update):

```js
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const planningSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Planning");
const bddSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("BDD");
const validValuesRange = "$C$2:$C$11";


function onEdit(e) {
  const editedRange = e.range;
  const editedSheetName = editedRange.getSheet().getName();
  const editedColumn = editedRange.getColumn();
  if (editedColumn == 3 && editedSheetName === planningSheet.getName()) {
    if (!editedRange.isBlank()) {
      editedRange.clearDataValidations();

    } else {
      var validValues = bddSheet.getRange(validValuesRange);
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
        .requireValueInRange(validValues, true)
        .setAllowInvalid(true)
        .build();
      editedRange.setDataValidation(rule);

    }
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: Example]

This is working based on the format from the sample Spreadsheet, you'll need to update names and ranges for other applications.